# Conditional awk command printing the 'else' statement only once

Tags: awk

Apologies for the confusing title. I'd like to process columnar files using a conditional awk statement. Basically, if the number 27606 is found in column 2, I want to print length($4)-length($5), otherwise I want to print "0" once if 27606 is not found in column 2.

Consider `present.txt`:

```
First   11111   Third   ABCDE   A
First   27606   Third   ABCDE   A
First   22222   Third   ABCDE   A
First   33333   Third   ABCDE   A
First   44444   Third   ABCDE   A
```

and `absent.txt`:

```
First   11111   Third   ABCDE   A
First   55555   Third   ABCDE   A
First   22222   Third   ABCDE   A
First   33333   Third   ABCDE   A
First   44444   Third   ABCDE   A
```

For `present.txt`, the output should simply be: 4.
For `absent.txt`, the output should simply be: 0.

I've tried the following:

`awk '{if ($2 ~ /27606/){print length($4)-length($5)} else { print "0" }}' file`

This 'works' in the way I want by printing '4' for `present.txt`, *however* it prints 0 for *every line* that doesn't have 27606 in column 2 in `absent.txt`... Output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

I've also tried:

`awk '$2 ~ /27606/ {found=1} END {if (!found) print "0"} {if (found) print length($4)-length($5)}' file`

This works with `absent.txt`: "0" is only printed once. However, for `present.txt`, length($4)-length($5) is printed for the first line matching 27606 in column $2 **as well as every subsequent line**. Output:

```
4
4
4
4
```

What command can I use so that the output from `present.txt` is '4', and the output from `absent.txt` is '0'? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the value is found, print out your calculated value and increment a counter. In an `END` block print 0 if the counter is 0:

```sh
awk '$2 == 27606 { print length($4) - length($5); found++ }
     END { if (!found) print 0 }' input.txt
```

If you want to only output one number even if the value is found multiple times:

```sh
awk '$2 == 27606 && !found { print length($4) - length($5); found++ }
     END { if (!found) print 0 }' input.txt
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! (I'll accept your answer once I'm able to in 6 minutes...)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like 27606 can only occur on 1 line max so all you'd need is:

```
$ awk '$2==27606{diff=length($4)-length($5); exit} END{print diff+0}' present.txt
4

$ awk '$2==27606{diff=length($4)-length($5); exit} END{print diff+0}' absent.txt
0
```

Comment: I ended up extending the end goal of running this code, and for that new usage, answer 1 works better. However, based on what I asked in this question, your solution works well. Thanks!